# TYPO3 meta description - Use closest

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have set the description meta using:

```
page.meta.description.field = description
```

Can I make it so child pages use the description from the closest page that has one set?

So if the root page has description1 then all sub-pages use it, unless a sub-page has it's own description2 in which case it and any sub-pages of it would use description2 and so on...

Answer (score 7):

two parts:

1. in your typoscript:

   `page.meta.description.data = levelfield:-1, description, slide`
2. in your Install-Tool add the field to the fields which should slide:

   `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONV_VARS']['FE']['addRootLineFields'] = 'description';`

added:
aside from straight slide to first non empty entry, you also have options to [collect](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/7.6/ContentObjects/Content/) all the entries along the rootpath:

**`.slide`** If set and no content element is found by the select command, the rootLine will be traversed back until some content is found.
Possible values are "-1" (slide back up to the siteroot), "1" (only the current level) and "2" (up from one level back). Use -1 in combination with collect:
**`.slide.collect`**: (integer /stdWrap) If set, all content elements found on the current and parent pages will be collected. Otherwise, the sliding would stop after the first hit. Set this value to the amount of levels to collect on, or use "-1" to collect up to the siteroot.
**`.slide.collectFuzzy`**: (boolean /stdWrap) Only useful in collect mode. If no content elements have been found for the specified depth in collect **mode, traverse further until at least one match has occurred.

`.slide.collectReverse`**: (boolean /stdWrap) Reverse order of elements in collect mode. If set, elements of the current page will be at the bottom.

Comment: I don't have access to the install tool, can it be done without?

Comment: not really. the Install tool writes to the file typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php which can be enhanced with typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php, where you can enter the assignements by hand - if you have access to the server (but then you can give yourself access to the install-tool in the same way by setting the hash for the install-tool password)

Answer (score 1):

You should not do this - you will get a bunch of error messages in the google webmaster tool complaining about duplicate meta tags. Google dont like this ... it is a kind of duplicate content.

Watch this video from google evangalist Matt Cutts: http://searchengineland.com/googles-matt-cutts-dont-duplicate-your-meta-descriptions-177706

"In short, it is better to let Google auto-create snippets for your pages versus having duplicate meta descriptions."